# How can I cached query result in class and then reuse it for searching based on parameter passed in a Method in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to implement search properties functionality in ASP.NET MVC web application, where the page has Experience list and each experience has a unique id assigned to it and has a list of properties. When the user clicks on one Experience it will display properties related to that experience. Now when the user clicks on another experience it will take both id's and return common properties. I have a class which cached the database result and store it.

```
public class GetExperienceResponse
{
    public string Experienceid { get; set; }
    public List<string> Properties { get; set; }
   //Example: Expereienceid="E1", Properties="P1,P2,P3" 
              Experienceid="E2",  Properties="P3,P4,P5"
}


public static List<GetExperienceAmenityResponse> GetExperience()
{
//returns experience and related properties here and cached it 
}
```

The method I am using for Search properties based on Experience clicked is:

```
public ActionResult ExperienceSearch(string id)
    {
        List<GetExperienceResponse> Experiences  = new List<GetExperienceResponse>();
        Experiences = GetExperience(); //Populate the Experience result list
       //logic for searching. When Click on Experience1, it will pass id "E1" and should display Properties "P1", "P2" and "P3". When Click on both Experience it should display common property which is "P3" here (Intersection of Experience 1 and  Experience 2).
        return View();
    }
```

What is the best approach to implement this search? Can I use LINQ query on the returned result? I will appreciate any help. Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You mention intersection and LINQ in your question; have you seen [`Intersect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.intersect?view=netframework-4.7.2)?

Comment: Yes, I have seen Intersect but I am not sure how it will work in my case for finding properties which are a list of strings. Thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. 
Do you want to cache your result per id? 
Do you want to cache your user choices? 
Do you want to search by more than one ids on your result ?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion. Yes I want to cache my result by id. Like when I load the data from the database for the first time , I want to cache them and then I want to use the same cached version for properties search based on experience id I pass. Please let me know if you need more clarification. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can have unique Cachekey for individual experience and have common cache key(hashkey by Experienceid1 &Experienceid2) for common property.